# Downloading large video Files

Tags: asp.net, .net, video, github, video-streaming

I am planning to storing large video files on GitHub and is looking for guidance on how to optimize the user experience for downloading these large files off GitHub.

Is there any way to make the files smaller on the upload, cloning the repo, or if there was another platform/service we could consider ?

Thanks,

Comment: If the files are for end-users, you should Google `CDN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, storing static contents on version control system such as GitHub is not best practices, and personally I haven't heard before!!

You can either use a service such as [Rackspace Cloud Files](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files) or [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Comment: Just FYI..Access to these files do not need to require a login, Users should be able to download without any authentication. Is it possible with Rackspace or Amazon s3? How is the download experience of large files?

Comment: *Is it possible with Rackspace or Amazon s3?* You need to configure with your website, so basically end user won't need to authenticate! *How is the download experience of large files* I've experienced with Amazon S3 and its pretty fast then others!!